# React vs ReactX vs Functional Programming vs Reactive Functional Programming vs Reactive Extensions

Tags: functional-programming, reactive

Could you please explain in simple terms what is the difference between all these terms. When reading through articles am seeing a maze of buzzwords but its getting 
little confused. What are the areas where these programming models be used.

Regards

Comment: Comparing paradigms and frameworks doesn't make much sense. FWIW, functional reactive programming is functional programming in the context of UIs.

Answer (score 6):

- *Functional Programming*: Very broad category. An approach to programming that can be used both in “traditional” languages or specialized functional languages. Main point is to minimize state and program without side-effects, preferably using “pure” functions in the mathematical sense, where a function return value is determined just by its arguments.
- *Functional Reactive Programming*: A style of structuring programs where the computation is driven by incoming events or signals.
- *React*: A JavaScript UI framework inspired both by functional programming and functional reactive programming. Its main point is to replace the tedious and error-prone DOM tree management with an automated algorithm driven by model updates.
- *ReactX*: No idea.

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: Correct term is Reactive Extensions (also known as ReactiveX), not ReactX. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactive_extensions